# Getting an instance within a Guice Module

Tags: dependency-injection, singleton, guice

I have this class:

```
public class CompositeSecurityAuthorizer implements SecurityAuthorizer {
    @inject @CompositeSecurityAuthorizerAnnot
    List<SecurityAuthorizer> authorizers; //Field Injection
}
```

I want to inject the `authorizers` field a `List<SecurityAuthorizer>` value.

In my module , I have the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
  bind(CompositeSecurityAuthorizer.class).in(Singleton.class);
  bind(StoreAuthorizer.class).in(Singleton.class);
  bind(SecurityAuthorizer.class)
      .annotatedWith(CompositeSecurityAuthorizerAnnot.class)
      .to(CompositeSecurityAuthorizer.class);
}

@Provides @CompositeSecurityAuthorizerAnnot
List<SecurityAuthorizer> provideAuthorizersList()
{
    List<SecurityAuthorizer> authList = new ArrayList<SecurityAuthorizer>();
    //How do I add StoreAuthorizer while maintaining a Singleton?
    //Will the line below do it through Guice magic?
    //authList.add(new StoreAuthorizer());
    return authList;
}
```

---

My question is embedded in the code comments.  When I'm adding `StoreAuthorizer` to that `List<SecurityAuthorizer>`:

- How do I ensure it's the same instance as other `StoreAuthorizer` references?
- Is that something Guice is just doing under the hood, so `new StoreAuthorizer()` really is calling an impl of `getInstance()` behind the scenes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provider methods allow injected arguments. The `StoreAuthorizer` passed to the method here will be the singleton bound in your module. Guice doesn't and can't do anything magical if you call a constructor yourself.

```
@Provides @CompositeSecurityAuthorizerAnnot
List<SecurityAuthorizer> provideAuthorizersList(StoreAuthorizer storeAuthorizer)
{
    List<SecurityAuthorizer> authList = new ArrayList<SecurityAuthorizer>();
    authList.add(storeAuthorizer);
    return authList;
}
```

As an aside, you may want to consider using the Guice Multibindings extension to create a `Set<SecurityAuthorizer>` rather than doing this yourself.

Comment: I forgot about MultiBinder.  So something like this?

    Multibinder<SecurityAuthorizer> securityBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), SecurityAuthorizer.class);
    securityBinder.addBinding().to(StoreAuthorizer.class);

Comment: @Snekse: Yep, something like that.

Comment: Opps, looks like Multibinder is not compatible with Gin.  
http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=111

Comment: Would your answer be any different if I needed to add 15 `SecurityAuthorizer` objects to that `authList`?

Comment: @Snekse: Well, you'd need 15 `SecurityAuthorizer` arguments to the method, differentiated by binding annotations or types or whatever. It'd be ugly, but I think it should work.

Comment: Ugg, the problem is there is 15 maybe for this list, but I have a *ton* of these kinds of things we need to do.  I'm converting an app using gwt-rocket to gin and the ApplicationContext.xml file is huge.

Comment: @Snekse: Guice can't magically initialize a variable for you in the middle of a method any more than it can magically do something when you call a constructor. So no, that wouldn't work... you'd just add `null` to the list. (I'd recommend editing your question when you have something more to ask that involves code... doesn't work too well in comments.)